# Cascade delete in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, sql-delete, cascade

I have a example of cascade delete but it looks too big and complicated, is there a way to shorten this code?

```
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleted(function ($parent) {
            // $versions = $parent->game_versions();
            $versions = $parent->game_versions;
            foreach($versions as $version){
                $version->delete();
            }
        });
    }
```

Someone can help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use CASCADE DELETE, you can modify the foreign key constraint in your migration that creates the game_versions table to include the onDelete method with a value of "cascade", like so:

```
Schema::create('game_versions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('game_id');
    $table->foreign('game_id')->references('id')->on('games')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('version_number');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This will ensure that when a Game record is deleted, all related GameVersion records with the corresponding game_id will also be deleted from the database.

Answer (score -1):

you can simplify the foreach as this.

```
foreach($versions as $version as $v)->delete()
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not valid php. Maybe oneliner: foreach($versions as $version) version->delete()

Answer (score -1):

For example, the following code will erase all game versions when a game is deleted:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted(function ($parent) {
        $parent->game_versions()->delete();
    });
}
```